# Working with concerns on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Edit: I implemented this again and I am getting this error.

I am working with Concerns. I took out some code of my app/models/user.rb and placed it into app/models/concenrs/following.rb. The source codes can be found on Gist, [here](https://gist.github.com/stefioan/7720562).

When I go to /dashboards I get this error on timeline.rb (i uploaded this file's code on Gist too).

```
undefined method `followed_user_ids' for #<User:0x4f6cfc8>
```

The error is on line 15 of timeline.rb.

The project can be found on [Github](https://github.com/stefioan/9FUN).

This seems to me that it does not load the module. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `ActiveSupport:Concern` instead of `ActiveSupport::Concern` (notice the double colon).

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake. The error I was getting yesterday is this new one.

Comment: The project on Github does not have app/models/concerns. You should probably make a new question with more details about your second problem.

Comment: The project on github is before commiting these simple changes (just making a concerns folder and putting following.rb in there) I described. There is no second problem as the first error was my syntax mistake. The real problem was that it does not recognize my concern.

Comment: `include` should be `included`. You also need to include the module into your User class.